# CSS positioning and z-index on card

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to code this card design:
[image: Image of the design]

However, I need some help with the positioning and z-index. This is how far I've come:

```css
.card {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  background: lightblue;
}
    
.card-hover-state {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #000000 0%, rgba(216,216,216,0.00) 100%);
  opacity: 0.6;
}
    
.card-hover-state-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 60%;
}
    
.card-hover-state-button {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-hover-state"></div>
  <div class="information-container">
    <div class="card-hover-state-title">Brace yourself - A fancy Lorem Ipsum Title is comming</div>
    <div class="card-hover-state-button">READ MORE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the text isn't showing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative` on `.card`, then you actually don't need `.card-hover-state` - you can use a pseudo element instead. Whichever of those you use, you need to add `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` to position it over the `.card` background.

Then I would make `.information-center` a `flex` parent and use `justify-content: space-between` to separate its children, and `align-items: center` to center them vertically, and add `position: relative` so it will have a position that puts it on top of the `absolute`ly positioned pseudo element (or `.card-hover-state`) that comes before it.

```css
.card {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.card::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -180deg,
    #000000 0%,
    rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.00) 100%
  );
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.information-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-hover-state-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  max-width: 60%;
}

.card-hover-state-button {
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="information-container">
    <div class="card-hover-state-title">Brace yourself - A fancy Lorem Ipsum Title is comming</div>
    <div class="card-hover-state-button">READ MORE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using below approach.

I just added `display:table` to your `.information-container` and assigned `width:100%` to take full parent `div` `width`, after that I assigned `.card-hover-state-title` and `.card-hover-state-button`
 to `position:relative` so they don't use the parent div's `opacity:0.6` and also added `display:table-cell` and `width` to get inline both.

I added CSS properties in the following classes:

```css
.information-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-hover-state-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
}

.card-hover-state-button {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.card-hover-state {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #000000 0%, rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.00) 100%);
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.information-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-hover-state-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
}

.card-hover-state-button {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-hover-state"></div>
  <div class="information-container">
    <div class="card-hover-state-title">Brace yourself - A fancy Lorem Ipsum Title is comming</div>
    <div class="card-hover-state-button">READ MORE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```